# ignite: how to save and re-load trained model

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ignite

Following is the piece of code i used to train my model. After that how and where can i save my model and read it back other than FileExporter class? is it only in a file or can i store it in a cache and access back?

```
IgniteCache<Integer, double[]> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("MLData_IRIS");

// extracting   sepal length, sepal width, petal length, petal width
IgniteBiFunction<Integer, double[], Vector> featureExtractor = new RangeExtractor(1, 5);
IgniteBiFunction<Integer, double[], Double> labelExtractor = new PointExtractor(0);

System.out.println(">>> Create new training dataset splitter object.");
TrainTestSplit<Integer, double[]> split = new TrainTestDatasetSplitter<Integer, double[]>()
    .split(0.5, 0.5);

IgniteBiPredicate<Integer, double[]> testData = split.getTestFilter();
IgniteBiPredicate<Integer, double[]> trainData = split.getTrainFilter();

// Set up the trainer
KMeansTrainer trainer = new KMeansTrainer()
    .withDistance(new EuclideanDistance())  //other metrics are HammingDistance, ManhattanDistance
    .withAmountOfClusters(3) // number clusters want to create
    .withMaxIterations(100)
    .withEpsilon(1.0E-4D)
    .withSeed(1234L);

long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

KMeansModel mdl = trainer.fit(
    ignite,
    cache,
    trainData,
    featureExtractor,
    labelExtractor
);

long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("time taken to build the model : " + (t2 - t1) + " ms");

System.out.println(">>> --------------------------------------------");
System.out.println(">>> trained model: " + mdl.toString(true));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now Ignite have only this mechanism - FileExporter.

But, for version 2.8 we already implemented model storage.

Sample for saving model:

```
ModelStorage storage = new ModelStorageFactory().getModelStorage(ignite);
        storage.mkdirs("/");
        storage.putFile("/my_model", serializedMdl);

        ModelDescriptor desc = new ModelDescriptor(
            "MyModel",
            "My Cool Model",
            new ModelSignature("", "", ""),
            new ModelStorageModelReader("/my_model"),
            new IgniteModelParser<>()
        );
        ModelDescriptorStorage descStorage = new ModelDescriptorStorageFactory().getModelDescriptorStorage(ignite);
        descStorage.put("my_model", desc);
```

Sample for loading model:

```
Ignite ignite = Ignition.ignite();

        ModelDescriptorStorage descStorage = new ModelDescriptorStorageFactory().getModelDescriptorStorage(ignite);
        ModelDescriptor desc = descStorage.get(mdl);

        Model<byte[], byte[]> infMdl = new SingleModelBuilder().build(desc.getReader(), desc.getParser());

        Vector input = VectorUtils.of(x);

        try {
            return deserialize(infMdl.predict(serialize(input)));
        }
        catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

Where *x* - is vector of doubles and *mdl* - is model name.

NOTE: this API will be available with release 2.8. But, you could try it right now if you will build Ignite from master branch.

Comment: Let me add that `ModelStorage` and all other saving approaches are based on pure Java serialization. So, you already can serialize it and save into cache or file and deserialize it back when you need it.